# Reschedule rask task to the next day if it falls on sunday in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I have defined a rake task to run on the 2nd and 17th of every month. But I don't want this task to run if 2nd and 17th fall on Sunday. In that case, the task should run on the next day. Any idea of how that can be achieved, anyone?

```
#run this task at 8am on 17th of every month
every '0 8 17 * *' do
  rake 'money:reminder', environment: ENV['RAILS_ENV']
end


#run this task at 8am on the 2nd day of every month
every '0 8 2 * *' do
  rake 'money:reminder', environment: ENV['RAILS_ENV']
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap your task in an ActiveJob and queue it to run later :

```
# Enqueue a job to be performed tomorrow at noon.
GuestsCleanupJob.set(wait_until: Date.tomorrow.noon).perform_later(guest)
```

(source : [railsguide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#enqueue-the-job))

In your case, with a condition on the weekday:

```rb
# your_class.rb
def self.reminder
  if Time.current.sunday?
    YourJob.set(wait_until: Date.tomorrow.noon).perform_later
  else
    YourJob.perform_later
  end
end

# schedule.rb
#run this task at 8am on 17th of every month
every '0 8 17 * *' do
  bundle exec rails runner 'YourModel.reminder'
end


#run this task at 8am on the 2nd day of every month
every '0 8 2 * *' do
  bundle exec rails runner 'YourModel.reminder'
end
```

edit : After reading your comment, it seems like your worker is a Sidekiq worker. If so, you can use :

```
HardWorker.perform_in(5.minutes, 'bob', 5)
HardWorker.perform_at(5.minutes.from_now, 'bob', 5)
```

(source : [getting started](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Getting-Started))

Comment: ReminderWorker.perform_async(office.id, money_ids,reminder.id) if money_ids.any?

How can I set this to run for tomorrow at 8 am? if it is a Sunday

Comment: I am not sure how to pass the arguments in perform_later enqueue job job

Comment: ReminderWorker.perform_later(office.id, money_ids,reminder.id).set(wait_until: Date.tomorrow.noon) if money_ids.any?

Should it be something like this?